# E2E test - repeater().column() providing inconsistent results

Tags: testing, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I'm writing some E2E tests for my Angular app. One thing I want to do is make sure a set of widgets are loaded into a dashboard view, and placed in the correct sequence when the app is initialized.

Five mock widgets are provided by a JSON array. Each widget dictionary in this array has a `seq` member over which I am ordering my data.

My template looks like:

```
<section id="dashboardApp" ng-cloak>
  <div class="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets | orderBy: 'seq'">
    <h3 ng-bind="widget.title"></h3>
    <div widget-view="widget"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

(The widget-specific portions of the templating are defined by partials dynamically loaded based on `widget.type` in the `widgetView` directive, but is too low level for the scope of this test).

My E2E scenario looks like:

```
it('should load mock widgets into correct order, by seq', function () {
  expect(repeater('div.widget', 'widgets').column('widget.seq'))
    .toEqual(['1','2','3','4','5']);
});
```

and is based on examples in the official Angular tutorial.

However, the value it compares against my expected result is an array with only two members. If I change the property I am inspecting in `.column()`, I get arrays of different lengths reported by the test runner. For instance,

`.column('widget.seq')` produces:
`["3","4"]`

`.column('widget.type')` produces:
`["chart","chart","simpleTable"]`

`.column('widget.title')` produces:
`["Site Overview","Order Alerts","widget1","widget3","widget2"]`

and so on.

I find this variation strange and unpredictable. For the record, those members that are reported DO display in the correct order, but the results are only partial, except when I look over `widget.title`...

Does anyone know what's going on?

[edit]

I was able to get something close to what I wanted by:

a) adding a new attribute to my `div.widget`s

b) writing a custom query

like so:

```
it('should load mock widgets into correct order, by seq', function () {
  var promise = element('div.widget').query(function (elements, done) {
    var seq = [];
    elements.each(function () {
      seq.push(parseInt(angular.element(this).attr('data-seq')));
    });
    done(null, seq);
  });
  expect(promise).toEqual([1,2,3,4,5]);
});
```

This works but requires including some extra junk in my application code (the `data-seq` attr). Seems a bit roundabout given that `expect().column()` is supposed to be able to handle this, right? Thoughts?

[/edit]

Comment: You can actually use `angular.forEach(elements, function(element){ ... })` to loop so you don't need jQuery, try it please.

Comment: @sza, `angular.forEach(elements, fn(el){})` iterates over several additional members of the `elements` object that don't have anything to do with the DOM. I was able to remove jQuery import from my workaround by using `angular.element(this).attr()` rather than `$(this).attr()` -- updated above